# How to fix System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//front end coding 
 <div class="form-group">
    <asp:FileUpload ID = "fupPhoto" runat="server" BorderColor="#EFEFEF" ForeColor="#9A9A9A"/>
 </div>
//back end coding 
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fupPhoto.PostedFile.FileName) + ".jpg";
        System.Drawing.Image image = Bitmap.FromFile(filename);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center; 
        Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D3D3D3");
        string text = "Culturely.Co"; 
        graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Arail", 30, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(color), new Point(268, 245)); 
        image.Save("watermarked" + filename); 
    }
}
```

I wish to add watermark on the image and save in the same file as the page but it show the error of `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` after I click button.

Comment: `Bitmap.FromFile` tries to load a file *from the local file system* - but you haven't saved it to the local file system as far as I can see. I suggest you use `Bitmap.FromStream(fupPhoto.FileContent)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet it do works but another problems occurs with the error message of A generic error occurred in GDI+ pointing the line image.Save("watermarked" + filename);

Comment: Well have you debugged to check where that's trying to save the file? I would be somewhat nervous of trying to save files to arbitrary user-specified places on your server's file system, to be honest. I'd probably either save to a database, or save to an absolute path in a "known good" location, using autogenerated filenames rather than ones specified in the request. (You could then separately have a mapping table if you wanted.)

Comment: @JonSkeet im not really understanding about what you trying to say

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your help. i have find the solution to solve it.

Comment: 'filename' contains no directory, so the current working directory will be used, which might not be what you want. Add a full path information to your filename ("C:\Somepath\watermarkedmyImage.jpg" instead of "watermarkedmyImage.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fupPhoto.PostedFile.InputStream); //Bitmap.FromFile(filename);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
            stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D3D3D3");
            string text = "Culturely.Co";
            graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Arail", 30, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(color), new Point(268, 245));
            //image.Save("watermarked" + filename);
            string filename = fupPhoto.FileName;
            string outputname = "Watermarked" + filename;
            image.Save("C:\\" + outputname);
```

The file cannot be replaced. Hence another name is needed to be used then it runs.
Thanks for those who had helped.